# Problems with remote rsync

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I have trouble using rsync to backup my local home folder to a remote server (chh2). When I type the following command:

```
  rsync -v -e ssh /home/* chh2@192.168.1.67:~/Documents/chh1_backup
```

I get the following error:

```
  Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11    
  forwarding.
  skipping directory chh1
  sent 16 bytes  received 12 bytes  18.67 bytes/sec
  total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

I have no trouble establishing a connection with ssh -X chh2@192.168.1.67
nor do I have any trouble with scp.

I have tried all combinations of the following lines in /etc/ssh/config:

```
 #   ForwardAgent no 
     ForwardX11 yes
 #   ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

and none of them made any difference. Does anyone know how to put me on the right path with this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing `skipping directory chh1` because `rsync` does not recurse into directories by default.  **Add the `-r` option to recurse**, or even better, `-a` (equivalent to `-rlptgoD`), which preserves a bunch of metadata to put into the copy.

<sup>[Explanation of `rsync -rlptgoD`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-rlptgoD):</sup>

[image: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-rlptgoD]

Comment: Thanks Deltik. Spot on! That solved the problem.

Comment: @ChristianHick: Glad to see your problem is solved!  You can indicate this by checking [the gray check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg2CP.png) to the left of this answer.